Configure multiple connection strings to the same database in .NET Aspire
In .NET Aspire, how can I model multiple connection strings to the same database?
In the example below, I want MigrationService to connect to the same db database but using a different connection string than ApiService in order to implement principal of least privilege (using two different SQL Users with two different database roles). I recognize different connection strings isn't particularly needed for local dev, but I want to figure out how to model it so I can use the same EF Core DbContext registrations locally as in production.
AppHost
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var db = builder.AddSqlServer("sql")
                .AddDatabase("db");

builder.AddProject<Projects.Parameters__MigrationService>("migrationservice")
       .WithReference(db);

builder.AddProject<Projects.Parameters_ApiService>("api")
       .WithReference(db); // TODO: use different connection string to same database

builder.Build().Run();

Example Connection Strings
(Different Users with different database roles)
Server=tcp:sql.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=MigrationServiceUser;Password=MigrationServiceUserPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Server=tcp:sql.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=ApiUser;Password=ApiUserPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Example EF Core DbContext Registrations
builder.AddSqlServerDbContext<MigrationServiceDbContext>("db");
        
// TODO: use different connection string than MigrationServiceDbContext
builder.AddSqlServerDbContext<ApiDbContext>("db");

public class MigrationServiceDbContext(DbContextOptions<QueryDbContext> options) : ApiDbContext(options);

I've tried to keep the example simple for StackOverflow, but here's the real app I'm working on if interested: AppHost | DbContext Registrations

What sort of mutation do you want to do with the connection string? Can you show an example?

@davidfowl, I just expanded the question a bit. Thanks.

So you want to change the user name and password for the database. Is the assumption that you have already setup the database with that other user?

Correct, the database already exists with the two users. I'm not using Aspire for provisioning or deployment (yet). When debugging locally, using the same connection string for both contexts is probably fine. But, I'd like to not have two different sets of DI registrations for the EF Core DbContexts by environment (local/Aspire vs. production).

If the database already exists, then you don't need to spin up a container. Is that the right assumption?

In production, the database exists. Locally, I would like to use the Aspire-created containerized db. I'm probably overthinking this.

How are you creating the user locally when you use the aspire created containerized db?

A potential (untested) solution could be to register the Aspire "db" only in development, otherwise register the production connectionstrings
    if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        builder.AddSqlServerDbContext<MyDbCoMigrationServiceDbContextntext>("db");
        builder.AddSqlServerDbContext<ApiDbContext>("db");
    }
    else
    {
        builder.AddSqlServerDbContext<MigrationServiceDbContext>("MigrationServiceDbConnectionString"); // in connectionstrings
        builder.AddSqlServerDbContext<ApiDbContext>("ApiDbConnectionString");
    }

